# Conversao de hexa para int e toupper nao funcionam

Tags: c++, hexadecimal

Estou precisando dde ajuda em relação a este codigo pois creiei tres funçoes

porem a função hexToInt nao esta convertendo corretamente somente funciona a conversao se os hexa for um inteiro tipo 19 e nao A ou 1D.

e as funçoes toUpper e toLower nao imprimem uma letra com acento

toUper ela tras os dados da seguinte forma abaixo:

MEU NOME é C++
ou seja ela nao imprime maiuscula a letra acentuada
o mesmo é dito para a função toLower abaixo:

meu nome É c++

o codigo é este abaixo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

std::string toLower(std::string s)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        s[i] = towlower(s[i]);
    return s;
}

std::string toUpper(std::string s)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        s[i] = towupper(s[i]);
    return s;
}

int hexToInt(std::string s)
{
    int res = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        int multiplier = 1;
        int exp = (s.size() - 1 - i);
        while (exp-- > 0)
            multiplier *= 16;
        int ch = s[i];
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
            res += multiplier * (ch - '0');
        else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
            res += multiplier * (ch - 'a');
        else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
            res += multiplier * (ch - 'A');
    }
    return res;

}

int main () {

  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{0}: "<<hexToInt("0");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{1}: "<<hexToInt("1");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{2}: "<<hexToInt("2");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{3}: "<<hexToInt("3");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{4}: "<<hexToInt("4");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{5}: "<<hexToInt("5");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{6}: "<<hexToInt("6");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{7}: "<<hexToInt("7");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{8}: "<<hexToInt("8");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{9}: "<<hexToInt("9");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{A}: "<<hexToInt("A");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{B}: "<<hexToInt("B");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{C}: "<<hexToInt("C");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{D}: "<<hexToInt("D");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{E}: "<<hexToInt("E");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{F}: "<<hexToInt("F");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{10}: "<<hexToInt("10");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{11}: "<<hexToInt("11");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{12}: "<<hexToInt("12");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{13}: "<<hexToInt("13");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{14}: "<<hexToInt("14");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{15}: "<<hexToInt("15");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{16}: "<<hexToInt("16");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{17}: "<<hexToInt("17");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{18}: "<<hexToInt("18");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{19}: "<<hexToInt("19");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{1A}: "<<hexToInt("1A");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{1B}: "<<hexToInt("1B");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{1C}: "<<hexToInt("1C");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{1D}: "<<hexToInt("1D");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{1E}: "<<hexToInt("1E");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{1F}: "<<hexToInt("1F");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\thexToInt{20}: "<<hexToInt("20");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\t"<<toUpper("meu nome é c++");
  std::cout<<"\n\n\t"<<toLower("MEU NOME É C++")<<"\n\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: O @diegofm já fez a gentileza de editar sua pergunta, mas lembre-se que sempre que tiver dúvidas com trecho de código, poste tudo na própria pergunta. Para formatar como código, selecione o trecho, e aperte control+K no teclado, ou use o botão `{ }` para formatar. Tem um preview embaixo do campo de postagem que serve para você conferir se está ok.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

Faltou somar 10 nestas linhas, pois o A vale 10 e não 0:

```
res += multiplier * (ch - 'a' + 10);
```

e

```
res += multiplier * (ch - 'A' + 10);
```

Portanto, a função fica assim:

```
int hexToInt(std::string s)
{
    int res = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        int multiplier = 1;
        int exp = (s.size() - 1 - i);
        while (exp-- > 0)
            multiplier *= 16;
        int ch = s[i];
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
            res += multiplier * (ch - '0');
        else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
            res += multiplier * (ch - 'a' + 10);
        else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
            res += multiplier * (ch - 'A' + 10);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Veja seu código já corrigido e funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Hlc8Mm)**.

Quanto às letras acentuadas, você precisa especificar o LOCALE nas chamadas.

Por exemplo, incluindo o `<locale>` nos seus *headers* e fazendo algo assim:

```
std::string toLower(std::string s)
{
    std::locale loc("pt_PT"); // Aqui é o problema, depende do compilador
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        s[i] = tolower(s[i], loc);
    return s;
}
```

Notar que nesse caso está sendo usado o `tolower` da `<locale>`.

Comment: dessa forma que vc usou a locale ele até compilou porem o erro que ele retorna é este: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
Abortado (imagem do núcleo gravada)

Comment: Justamente, voce precisa ver na documentação do compilador quais são os locales disponiveis. pus "pt_PT" de exemplo, mas isso varia, nem todos os locales estão da mesma forma em todas as libs padrão. Por exemplo, tem caso que o formato é "Germany_german", tem casos que vc pode usar o formato curto e o encoding "en_US.utf-8", por exemplo. Precisa olhar a documentação do compilador/lib utilizado para saber o que por no lugar do "pt_PT".